# piling of two diffrent types of coins and permutation

Tags: permutations, combinations, problem-solving

You have an unlimited supply of 2 types of coins(coin-1 and coin-2). You are asked to build a pile of 1000 coins such that the number of coins between any two coin-2 is not equal to five. So what is the maximum number of coin-2 that can be included in the pile?

i know permutation and combination bit well but this question seems different and unique to me, how to tackle such problem? please help, thank you.

Comment: So basically this is equal to building a string of length 1000 from A and B, so that the substring "BAAAAAB" is not present.

Comment: The approach of every even coin (only) is coin-2 is no good, since there are **presumably** 5 coins between positions 2 and 8.  The approach of every third coin, would work but is inferior to repeating the pattern of BBBBAAAAAA.  This pattern leads to 400 coins.  So the problem *semi-reduces* to showing that 400 is maximum, or showing an example for $k > 400$ and then proving that $k$ is maximum.

Comment: @MattiP. Although I could easily be wrong, I am interpreting the problem differently than you have commented.  As I see it, there must be no occurrence of BxxxxxB, where x can be A or B.

Comment: Correction to my 1st comment: bbaabbaabbaa... seems to work, so the maximum seems to be at least 500 (since 1000 is divisble by 4).

Comment: @user2661923 I got 502 as maximum

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja Did your pattern generally follow my last comment, with a minor variation, or did you come up with an entirely new pattern?

Comment: @user2661923 posted an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evaluate the pile from bottom to top and list all the locations of coin-2: $\{x_{1},…,x_{m}\}$.

Say that there are no coin-2 pair with five coins between them. Then there are no $i<j$ that satisfy $x_{i}+6=x_{j}$ because otherwise there will be five coins between coin number $i$ and coin number $j$. Consequently, $\{x_{1},…,x_{m}\}$ and $\{x_{1}+6,…,x_{m}+6\}$ are $2m$ distinct integers between $1$ and $1006$. This give us an upper bound for $m$; $2m\leq1006\to m\leq 503$

However, $503$ is not the answer. Notice that $\{x_{1},…,x_{m}\}$ and $\{x_{1}+6,…,x_{m}+6\}$ are identical in modulo $6$ so if we write these in modulo $6$ we will get even number of each of $0,1,2,3,4,5$. Write $1$ to $1006$ in modulo $6$ and you’ll see that $1,2,3,4$ appear $168$ times while $5,0$ appear $167$ times. Means at least one number with $0$ in modulo $6$ and one number with $5$ in modulo $6$ will not appear. Therefore the upper bound need to be revised: $2m\leq 1006-2\to m\leq 502$

Turn out, stacking $6$ coin-2 and $6$ coin-1 alternatingly gives us the desired pile and a total of $502$ coin-2.

Comment: yes, I got it, bbbbbbaaaaaabbbbbbaaaaaa... works.  Now, you have to prove that 502 is a maximum (if possible).  $2^{1000} \approx 10^{300}$ is clearly too big to pc-computer-sanity-check.  A reasonable alternative is to sanity-check the lesser case of 30 coins, since $2^{30} \approx 10^9$ should be small enough to pc-computer-sanity-check.

Comment: Check my second paragraph, I have proven that the maximum cannot be higher than $503$. If we want to have $503$, all numbers from $1$ to $1006$ must appear, try it and you’ll realize why $502$ is the max

Comment: +1 to your answer.  However, I question the validity of your proof, which assumes that the optimal approach is to have blocks of consecutive coin-2's, followed by blocks of consecutive coin-1's.  While I strongly suspect that this is true, it is unclear to me that you have proven it.  However, it could be my shortcoming: it could be that you have actually proven it, and I am simply not grasping it.

Comment: @user2661923 I revised it, how about now?

Comment: Yes, it finally sank in, elegant proof.